# Not inserting data into SQL Server database using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, visual-studio-code

I'm writing a chat application in web API using C#, ASP.NET in VS code using a SQL Server database. The connection is working, I wrote the database in a `.cs` file and I added with `EF Migration`. Maybe I have a problem with the `SqlCommand`.

Here is the code:

```
public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
{
    string connn;
    connn = "Server=DESKTOP-U7SBTFN;Database=BCchat;Uid=sa;Pwd=123456789;";

    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connn);

    try 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySql...");
        con.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Connection Open!");

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("insert into Messages(Username, Message) values ('"+user+"','"+message+"')", con);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
    }

    con.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    Console.WriteLine($"user={user}, message={message}");

    await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
}
```

Here is the code for the Messages.cs and for the DBContext.cs:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace probagetrequest.Models
{
    [Table("Messages")]
    public class Messages
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace probagetrequest.Models
{
    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Messages> Messagees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Because you are using SQL commands and Entity Framework both at the same time. I`m not exactly sure what you want to have working.

Comment: @Josjr87 please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide about how to ask StackOverflow questions.

Comment: @szaszagado should check it ;-)

Comment: sorry, i'm learning programming and i'm a little bit confused with the databases. I want to store the users and the messages in a database. Before I made it in MongoDB, and its worked, but now i needed to change to MSSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't execute the command from what I can tell. I'm not sure what the EF part is doing so will ignore that.

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Messages (Username, Message) VALUES (@username, @message)";
var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", user);
cmd.Paramaters.Add("@message", message);

//Execute
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Jsjr87 already mentioned; you use the **EF** AND **SQL-Commands**. With the Entity Framework you usually didn't code any sql commands.

First, save your connection string to SQL Server in a Json file (`appsettings.json`)

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-U7SBTFN;Database=BCchat;Uid=sa;Pwd=123456789;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

In the `DbContext` set the connection string;

```
public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
{
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
}
```

To do a Insert with your message;

```
using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
{
    var message = new Messages { Username  = user, Message = name };
    db.Messages.Add(message);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: `appsettings.json` suggests ASP.NET **Core** - but the OP isn't mentioning "Core" in any way, shape or form ...

Answer (score 0):

In your question there is EF implementation.
You can use the EF to insert the data

```
using (var db = new YourDBContext())
{
 //add to EF Model
 //save change
}
```